# Error: Cannot find ramdisk "hd(0)/boot/grub/menu.lst"

Tags: xen, paravirtualization

I have a dom0 and try to run domU with config like this:

```
kernel      = '/root/xen/dist/install/usr/local/lib/xen/boot/pv-grub-x86_32.gz'
ramdisk     = 'hd(0)/boot/grub/menu.lst'

vcpus       = '2'
memory      = '1024'

root        = '/dev/sda1 ro'
disk        = [
                  'file:/opt/VSG.img,sda1,w',
              ]
name        = 'test.my.flat'



   vif         = [ 'ip=192.168.1.1,mac=00:16:3E:AC:D7:C8' ]

on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

after : xm create -c /etc/xen/test.my.flat.cfg

```
Error: Cannot find ramdisk "hd(0)/boot/grub/menu.lst


root@l2-coord-1: /root# mount -o loop,ro,offset=32256 /opt/VSG.img /mnt/
root@l2-coord-1: /root# cat /mnt/boot/grub/menu.lst 
default 0
timeout 5

title VSG
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /bzImage plat=vsg platgen=none quiet
    initrd /initramfs-vsg

root@l2-coord-1: /root#
```

I'm not anderstend what''s wrong. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**menu.lst** is not a **initrd** image.

That is your problem here.

The next problem is that your kernel is not a kernel but a xen-hypervisor. The hypervisor replaces the kernel on a Dom0. On a DomU you need a xen-kernel to run it in PV-mode.